# get information from a website in an organized way

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to web-scrape a website with Python and I'm having some trouble. I've already red a looooot of articles online and questions here and I still can't do what I need to do.
I have this website:

https://beta.nhs.uk/find-a-pharmacy/results?latitude=51.2457238068354&location=Little%20London%2C%20Hampshire%2C%20SP11&longitude=-1.45959328501975

and I need to print the name of the store and it's adress, and save it on an file (can be csv or excel). I've tried with selenium, pandas, beautiful soup and nothing worked :(

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Where is the code that you have tried with?

Comment: ^^ There are also multiple results - are you wanting to retrieve one, all, first page only (if multiple pages) ?

Comment: all of them!!! I need to know all the stores that exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import xlsxwriter

workbook  = xlsxwriter.Workbook('File.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

request = requests.get("https://beta.nhs.uk/find-a-pharmacy/results?latitude=51.2457238068354&location=Little%20London%2C%20Hampshire%2C%20SP11&longitude=-1.45959328501975")
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find_all("div", class_="results__details")
formed_data=[]
for results_details in data:
    formed_data.append([results_details.find_all("h2")[0].text,re.sub(' +',' ',results_details.find_all("p")[1].text.replace('\n',''))])
row=col=0
for name, adress in (formed_data):
    worksheet.write(row, col, name)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, adress)
    row += 1
workbook.close()
```

[image]

Comment: This is a really beautiful solution. You've just saved me! Thankssss

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get("https://beta.nhs.uk/find-a-pharmacy/results?latitude=51.2457238068354&location=Little%20London%2C%20Hampshire%2C%20SP11&longitude=-1.45959328501975")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find_all("div", class_="results__details")

for container in data:
  Pharmacyname = container.find_all("h2")
  Pharmacyadd  = container.find_all("p")
  for pharmacy in Pharmacyname:
      for add in Pharmacyadd:
          print(add.text)
          continue
      print(pharmacy.text)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Shepherds Spring Pharmacy Ltd is 1.8 miles away

       The Oval, 
       Cricketers Way, 

       Andover, 
       Hampshire, 
       SP10 5DN
      01264 355700

Map and directions for Shepherds Spring Pharmacy Ltd at The Oval
Services available in Shepherds Spring Pharmacy Ltd at The Oval
Open until 6:15pm today
Shepherds Spring Pharmacy Ltd
Tesco Instore Pharmacy is 2.1 miles away

       Tesco Superstore, 
       River  Way, 

       Andover, 
       Hampshire, 
       SP10 1UZ
      0345 677 9007

      .
      .
      .
```

> Note: You could create separate lists for `pharmacy_name` and
>   `pharmacy_add` to store the data and then write to the files. PS. You
>   could also strip off the unwanted text from the lists (let's say the
>   text after the Phone number from each pharmacy)